# Facebook notify for invite sent

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog

I have a little problem with dialog for invite friends

This is the code that I'v used:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

with my app ID.

I can choice my friends from the facebook dialong and invite they.

The response from Javascript callback is this:

[image: Request callback response]

But, why my friend don't receive the invitation from my app?

my friend == I, with two differents accounts.

The code is this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector();">Facebook</a>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'myid',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth: true
  });

  function sendRequestToRecipients() {
    var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to: user_ids, 
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Check bla from your friends.'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
</script>
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the javascript you've written?

Comment: @longhairedsi update in the question. Thanks

Comment: I can see nothing obvious wrong with this code, is your app a Canvas app?

Comment: Another user reported the same issue, I can see that the request was successful (based on the console). So I prefer you check the [Bugs](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) listing and if you couldn't find anything add one yourself.

Comment: Uhm, ok now I'v set canvas,
but i want to use this code outside facebook into a website, not facebook app. 

Which url must I set in URL CANVAS and Secure URL canvas?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use a request for an external website. This is from your linked code page above "Note: Requests are only available for Canvas apps and not websites. Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request."

Comment: uhm Thanks... and what is the way for websites?

Comment: You can use this code on a website but the landing app for the request must be a canvas app. You could potentially redirect users to your website from the canvas app.

Comment: Can I redirect users from canvas to my app?

Comment: @longhairedsi then how this site idiotminds.com using this feature in an extenral website, and yes I checked it, and its sending users notification...checkout the button at right column of site...

Comment: @vikasdevde, fb change a lot of stuff in a year, it may now be possible to do this(i haven't checked). But what you need to check is: where does the url in the request received by the user point to?  (it was always possible to send the request, just not point it to the correct destination url)

Comment: @longhairedsi can you please look at it, I am looking for this stuff, I looked at the code of that site, and implemented the same on my site, but its neither sending notification, nor invitation in apps tab..

Answer (score 1):

Requests is a feature that is only available to Canvas apps.  It is not available for Facebook for Websites aka Connect apps.

Citation:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

> Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas apps and not websites. Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

Comment: In my opinion:  

Canvas apps are the premier level of Facebook apps, at least from Facebook's perspective.  By being presented within an iframe they make your app look (to the user) like it is part of Facebook.  And Facebook serves ads up in their surrounding chrome.  So Facebook reserves some platform features to be exclusive to platform apps, presumably to incent developers to make sure they have at least some presence as a canvas app.